# Who were students of both the Vilna Gaon and the Maggid of Mezrich

Tags: rabbis, chasidut-hasidism, historical-figures, vilna-gaon

I know [Rav Avraham Kalisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Kalisker) was, and Mordechai Babroisk. I know there were others, but there seems to be quite a few more.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why is this particularly relevant from a Judaism perspective?

Comment: Obviusly cuz they had different hashkafos.

Comment: do you have another source besides wikipedia that corroborates that rav avraham kalisk started as a talmid of the gra?